# Should I use Flash Authoring Tool to draw my game characters of AS3 for it all?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, user-interface

Although I am sure I will use Flash to display my games in browsers what I am not sure about is if I should use the Flash Authoring Tool to draw my characters which I want to be vector based characters or if I should code everything in AS3.

Maybe it is just a personal thing but I would rather code everything by hand with the Flex SDK and compile it with the command line compiler. Is this logical or should I really think about using the Flash Authoring Tool to draw my characters and code it in with flex?

Hopefully get some AS3 developers out there with experience enough to answer this question.

Comment: I'd say use the Flash IDE to draw/animate the characters...tick the Export for Actionscript on the MovieClips you need to access from actionscript, tick Export SWC from the Publish Settings in Flash and then just use the classes from the swc file in Flex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you goal is vector graphics you can either build them in flash and export as a swc for use in flex.

Another option is build the assets in illustrator and export them in FXG format which you can then use flex. FXG is a version of SVG for flash/flex.

If the animation is more character based then i would go with Flash, but if it is just objects moving around the screen like spaceships or non characters then FXG would be fine. It will boil down to just what you prefer to work in really.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have thought about FXG and illustrator. Actually I was just looking for someone that was coding everything and validation but I haven't got that so far

Comment: sure I understand. I am going to be building some games for a client soon. I tend to build games in flash IDE but I write all my code in external .as files in flash builder for the better coding environment.

Comment: @Boyd, if you've open sourced an AS3 project, powerflasher will give you a FDT licence for free. (It's better than Flash Builder for pure AS work)

Comment: @body, do you have any resources for building games?

Comment: What type of game are you building? There are a lot of code out there, it just depends on what you are trying to do. There are some great flash game books you can find on amazon.com as well for $20-$35 which are great.

Comment: The game is like an educational game. Hard to explain but point is to remember 3000 Chinese Characters over a year.

Comment: Well not sure what to tell you. I would maybe start by finding some games like what you are trying to build and start from there. If your goal is testing memory then maybe memory or matching games would be a place to start. Or maybe you should look more into eLearning type setups where you teach a lesson and then quiz on it.

Comment: lol, thanks for the advice. The objective is to be fun and then learn things :)